# how can i find out how busy sql server is with IO using @@IO_BUSY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out how busy my sql 2000 server in terms of CPU and IO through a T-SQL query.

currently I am using the following to find the CPU Usage %:

```
  DECLARE
  @CPU_BUSY int
  , @IDLE int

  SELECT
  @CPU_BUSY = @@CPU_BUSY
  , @IDLE = @@IDLE

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:500'

  SELECT
  (@@CPU_BUSY - @CPU_BUSY)/((@@IDLE - @IDLE + @@CPU_BUSY - @CPU_BUSY) *
  1.00) *100 AS CPUBusyPct
```

However when I try a similar method to find the IO I get very low IO figures when I know the server is under load:
      DECLARE
      @IO_BUSY int
      , @IDLE int

```
  SELECT
  @IO_BUSY = @@IO_BUSY
  , @IDLE = @@IDLE

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:500'

  SELECT
  (@@IO_BUSY - @IO_BUSY)/((@@IDLE - @IDLE + @@IO_BUSY - @IO_BUSY) *
  1.00) *100 AS IOBusyPct
```

Are these methods even correct to reasonably estimate the server loads levels over a 500ms time period?

Any better suggestions?

I've tried sp_monitor but calling it every 1 second gives strange results, with the % going over 100

Answer (score 1):

> [@@IO_BUSY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177599.aspx) ... is cumulative for all CPUs, so it may
> exceed the actual elapsed time
>
> [@@CPU_BUSY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186925.aspx) ... is cumulative for all CPUs, so it may
> exceed the actual elapsed time

I'd recommend using performance counters instead, they are much more accurate. [Process object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) for CPU and [SQL Server, Wait Statistics Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190732.aspx) for various SQL waits.